Azure devops variable that lists git commit titles since last azure devops build?
I'm working on updating a build pipeline to log as much information about the build as possible. The only thing left that I need is the list of commits since the last build. I'm sure there's a way to use git to do that, but for each completed build, there's already a "View Changes" button which lists exactly what I want, so I'm trying to find if Azure Devops might have a variable already defined with this information so I don't have to write more code than necessary. I can't imagine that Devops does a git call every time you press that "View Changes" button.
I checked the list of Build variables and all I found was Build.SourceVersionMessage which only lists the last commit title, but I need the rest of them.
Does anyone know if there's a Devops variable that stores the list of commits since the last build? If not, I'll have to go the git route.

there may be a variable, otherwise you can look into azure devops API, and look for a resource which would give you the list of last builds.

I am afraid that Azure DevOps Pipeline doesn't have predefined variables that can show the commit lists since last build.
The predefined variables in Azure DevOps can only support showing the current build commit information(e.g. Build.SourceVersionMessage ).

The only thing left that I need is the list of commits since the last build.

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can Powershell/Bash task to run the Rest API: Builds - Get Build Changes to directly get the commit changes since last build.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version=7.1-preview.2

PowerShell sample:
$token = "$(PAT)"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectName/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildID)/changes?api-version=7.1-preview.2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

foreach($commitinfo in $response.value)
{
   $commitid = $commitinfo.id
   $commitmessage = $commitinfo.message
   echo $commitid
   echo $commitmessage
  
}

Result:

Then you can use logging command to define variable based on your requirement.
On the other hand, when you click the View Changes option in Pipeline UI, it will run Rest API at backend to get the changes between Pipelines. You can check the Browser Network trace to confirm it.
For example:

